# Calculus problem - Unknown variable in a quadratic

Tags: calculus

Is there an $a$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -3} \frac{10x^2+ax+a+8}{x^2+x-6}$ exists?

I can't seem to find how to actually solve it other than guessing, and I'm not sure there actually is a solution.

Comment: Could you show us your work so we could help you understand the problem better?

Comment: Well the denominator is 0 when x=-3.  So if the numerator is *not* 0 at x=-3 the function "blows up".  Otherwise if the numerator *does* equal zero we *might* (or might not have a removable singularity).  So first thing to try is set x to -3, set the numerator to 0, and solve for a.  Then see if that limit exists.

Comment: Ok, I substituted -3 in for x, set the numerator to 0 and got 49 as my 'a' value. The only problem is that I can't seem to find a way to factor the numerator as it ends up being 10x^2 + 49x +57.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider $2$ cases, when the numerator is evaluated to $0$ and when it is not at $x=-3$.

For the case when the numerator is $0$,

You can use L'hopital's rule and evaluate $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -3} \frac{20x+a}{2x+1}$$

Alternatively, $$10x^2+49x+57=(x+3)(10x+19)$$ Since we know that the numerator evaluates to $0$ at $x=-3$, $x+3$ is a factor.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer, this question was from an exam 5 years ago and the course must have taught L'hopital's rule, which is why I couldn't figure it out. Thank you for the solution though.

Comment: L'hopital's is optional actually, see my edit.

Comment: Right, it's been a long time since I have had to factor polynomials, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

For the limit to exist, the numerator must evaluate to $0$. Hence,

$$10(-3)^2+a(-3)+a+8=0$$ or $$a=49.$$

This is a necessary condition, we still have to show that it is sufficient. Indeed

$$10x^2+49x+57$$ isn't a perfect square so that $x=-3$ is a simple root of both numerator and denominator.